# A regular expression that replaces a group with hard coded text

Tags: regex, splunk, regex-group

First of all, I'm not sure if this is something you can even do in regular expressions. If you can, I have no idea on how to search for how to do it.

Let's say I have text:

```
Click <a href="/follow">this link</a> for more information.
```

And a regular expression:

```
<a[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>
```

The application of the regular expression would yield this for group 1:

```
this link
```

Let's say I wanted to write the regular expression to instead return hard coded text for group 1

```
<a[^>]*>(${{replacement text}}[^<]*)</a>
```

(*this is made up syntax by the way*)

So that the application of the regular expression to the text would yield this for group 1:

```
replacement text
```

Is this possible?

Here's another example just to solidify my objective:

Examples of text:

```
serverNode1/appPortal
serverNode1/appPortal2
serverNode1/appPortal3
```

My regular expression

```
appPortal((?:?{{"1"}}\b)|(?:\d))
```

(*using the same made up syntax*)

The expected output for the first character group should be

```
1
2
3
```

(The point of the expression is to match the word break and replace it with "1" or otherwise use the digit character class to match a digit. The sub-groups are made optional with the `?:` so the outside group is still group 1).

What is the point of this you may ask? I am using [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com) to do field extractions, and I'd like for the field to be extracted as 1, 2, or 3, like in my above example, and I can only rely on the regular expression groups to give me the fields (as in, I don't have anywhere to put code to say if group 1 == "" then change to "1").

Comment: You can use a programming language? Ie: Python, PHP, Perl?

Comment: Based on the way you have described the problem, I'm pretty sure it isn't possible. If you can show a code snippet or a screenshot, of where you are doing this, it might provide sufficient context for a clever workaround, but regex matches don't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, as the regular expressions defined, it is not possible. By definition, regular expressions match the patterns in the text. To be clear, regexp engine returns matches that are always part of the original string, nothing more. There are some regex extensions that allows to specify name of the capturing group, but it does not transform the match.

The behaviour you described can be easy achieved processing the regex match in any programming language, but it also can be achieved by combining regex substitution and parsing.

For example, `s/appPortal(?!\d)/appPortal1/` will replace "appPortal" without the digit after it with "appPortal1" and then you can apply another regex to build the match you want.

Comment: This was essentially the answer I was looking for: is it possible? No, it is not. I have to rely on SO for these sort of questions, since _all_ possibilities of regex (or any language) are not already documented.